# jQuery parallax scrolling for iPhone?

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, ipad, parallax

I'm looking for a fast, responsive parallax scrolling plugin for iPhone/iPad.  Has anyone had any experience with the performance of parallax plugins?  The ones I've tried lag behind.  Just wondering.  Thanks!

Comment: You are looking for [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) and also read [How to build parallax scroll on an iOS device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592788/how-to-build-parallax-scroll-on-an-ios-device)

Comment: I figured this would be closed...I know it's off topic but I couldn't find anything.  @TusharGupta I did try that before posting.  It as slow on one iPhone, but I tested it on another and it was fine.  Thanks!  :)  If you can post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I posted it as answer before bit i got down-voted i have un-deleted that post .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)

> Stand-alone parallax scrolling JavaScript library for mobile (Android,
>   iOS, etc.) and desktop in just over 9.6k (minified) or 4.5k (minified
>   + gzipped).

Also Read [How to build parallax scroll on an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592788/how-to-build-parallax-scroll-on-an-ios-device)